# Certificate Warnings When Directly Accessing Microsoft Store from Outlook 2019 Desktop Software

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2019

I am getting continuous certificate warnings when accessing the Microsoft Store from within Microsoft Outlook 2019 (Desktop version). It happens whenever I attempt to access the Add-Ins section from the Outlook toolbar i.e. Home -> Get Add-Ins.

I reviewed various technical websites to find a solution but the results are either unrelated or do not apply to the same software version.

As this is my first post on this site, I am unable to embed images in my posts but I have attached a screenshot of the error as follows:

[image: error]

Edit: Requested screenshot of certificate as follows:

[certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugWDe.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful to also post a screen shot of the dialog you get by clicking **View Certificate**.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this is an attempt by Windows to caution you about the website you are visiting as it is finding some discrepancies with its certificate.

Please refer to this article: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-identity-of-this-website-cannot-be-verified